How to select one FRA among many having the same time to maturity (Yield Curve Construction)
This question is related to Yield Curve Construction. I am using the old method described in this article. For the second region of the yield curve (page 8), FRAs are used. The zero-coupon yield can be computed using equation 28, from which one can derive :
$$ D(t,T_2)  = \frac{D(t,T_1) }{1+\delta(T_1,T_2)F(t;T_1,T_2)}$$
The thing is that there exist on the market several FRAs with the same time to maturity (T_2 in the equation).
Example : There are 2 FRAs with time to maturity = 4M. Both can be used to compute D(t,T_2) in the above equation.

We can set $T_1 = 1M$. We have for example $D(t,T_1) = 0.178552765$. Computing $D(t,T_2)$ with FRA "EUR1X4F" (starting in 1 month, maturing 3 months later), leads to $D(t,T_2)$ = 0.174110794.
If we rather set $T_1= 3M$, we have $D(t,T_1)=0.125566588$ (3M Euribor Rate). Using FRA "EUR3X4F" and the same logic, we have $D(t,T_2) = 0.124507761$.
Which FRA should we choose here? Is there any rational method for that?

a 1x4 is a 3m tenor FRA, whilst a 3x4 is a 1m tenor FRA. Mixing and matching different tenors for one curve will create garbage. For one curve use FRAs all with consistent tenors.

Thanks, I am still trying to understand the whole thing about that. It completely makes sense the way you say it. Would you maybe have some documentation you could recommend, that will help me understand better how lack of consistency could affect a yield curve? Here for example, should we consider FRAs with maturity 1M or 3M? What would be the logic?  Thanks

If you are trying to construct a curve that forecasts 1M-IBOR rates you use instruments with 1M tenors and similarly for 3M. If you do not know what curve you are trying to construct I suggest you start with trying to understand that aspect.

The very paper you have linked to make this apparent in its introduction and throughout the paper
